# push notifications with azure in windows phone 8 app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, windows-phone-8, push-notification, toast

I am using Azure services in my windows phone 8 app to send push notifications and toast notifications by following the steps mentioned [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-get-started-push/).

However as mentioned in the comments below on the link, `HttpNotificationChannel does not have a Uri property`, it's `ChannelUri`, so the code to create a new Registrations object need to be changed.

Could anyone suggest a turnaround or a solution to this bug?

Thanks!

Comment: can you clearify a bit, I couldn't understand what you asked?

Comment: @deeiip as the steps go on in the tutorial in the link,under the section "Add push notifications to your app", at point 3 there is a line of code written as "var registration = new Registrations { Handle = CurrentChannel.Uri };" . The .uri part is invalid in visual studio 2012. as there is no such thing as .uri in Currenchannel.Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
Handle = CurrentChannel.ChannelUri.ToString();
```

Comment: I did exactly the same! The code compiled too but there was no trace of a notification or tileupdate. This makes the coding error free but logically incorrect.